# I get no elevate dialog anymore

Tags: windows, google-chrome, uac, elevation

Whenever I launch a program, try to save files in 'C:\Program Files' and more, I don't get the Administrator Privileges dialog anymore. (Started about a month ago)

I can't run the chrome flash plugin anymore also, it works only if I enable the ActiveX flash plugin and disable the built-in player. After removing the ActiveX, I discovered that launching chrome as Admin using the right click method, makes it work.

Any ideas on fixing this problem?

Comment: Which version of Windows? Have you changed the UAC settings? Can you check what level the slider's set to? Also try running `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt.